# Excluir o "X" no Cabeçalho no R

Tags: r

Estou importando um arquivo csv para o R e o nome de cada coluna está aparecendo a letra "X" antes do nome original. Por exemplo:
Nomes dos campos no csv: `1.2_cidade`; `2_UF`.
Nomes dos campos após a importação: `X1.2_cidade`; `X2_UF`.

Como faço para importar sem o "X"?

Comment: Tente `names(dados) <- sub("^X", "", names(dados))`. (`dados` é o nome da data frame.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente olhar para o argumento `check.names` em `?read.csv`.

```
read.csv("dados.csv", check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode estar colocando muitos argumentos na função `read.csv`, eu tinha esse problema as vezes, quando colocava o argumento quote, e etc, agora normalmente só escrevo o comando assim e costuma dar certo (meus arquivos .csv, são salvos com unidade decimal separada por **virgula**), indicando que a separação das colunas é por **;** e a unidade decimal separa por **,**.

```
read.csv("nome_do_arquivo.csv",sep=";",dec=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o R não aceita o nome de variável, função ou coluna de `data.frame` iniciando com numérico, ponto ou subtraço. Por isso ele adiciona o **X**.

```
data <- data.frame('1.2_cidade' = c(1:2), '2_UF' = c(1:2))

data
   X_1.2_cidade X2_UF
1            1     1
2            2     2
```

A melhor solução é renomear as colunas sem o `X`, números, ponto ou subtraço, pois, mesmo forçando você pode ter, em algum momento, problemas na invocação.

```
colnames(data) <- sub("^[X0-9._]+", "", colnames(data))

data
  cidade UF
1      1  1
2      2  2
```